# Creating filters for listservs

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I know how to create filter for specific mailing list but I want the filter to avoid directly archiving mails which have my mail id in it or my name. Either in the cc or to.

Any idea how I can do that?

Update: Sometimes there are cases where the person who is replying is not even mentioning my name or has my gmail id in the for or cc but just the mailing list in the cc. How do I also avoid those mails from being archived directly?

Comment: just applied the filter in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set the filter to exclude emails containing your own email address by entering a minus sign (-) followed by your email address in the To field of the filter settings.

For example, to automatically archive email sent to mylist@list.com, but not when myemail@gmail.com is also a recipient:

- Go to Settings
- Click Filters
- Click Create a New Filter
- Enter the following in the To field:
  mylist@list.com -myemail@gmail.com
- Click Create filter with this search
- Check Skip the Inbox (and any other actions we want the filter to take)
- Click Create Filter

Although we're entering the email addresses in the To field, it gets applied to both To and Cc.

Comment: i am trying to create filter for received rather than sent. So do i follow the same steps and simply add `mylist@list.com -myemail@gmail.com` in the From field?

Comment: The -myemail@gmail.com definitely needs to stay in the To field, since you want Gmail to filter out emails that have your address in the To or Cc fields.  The mylist@list.com part actually depends on how the mailing list is set up.  Most mailing lists are set up to show the mailing list address in the To field of the email that you receive.  So check the emails that you've received from the list -- if it's set up that way, then create the filter exactly as I explained.

Comment: (continued) However, if the list address happens to be in the From field, then you'll need to configure the filter with the list address in the From field too.

Comment: hey ya you were right. It does come in the To field. Did not notice that. Also how should I modify if there are more than one mail list in the To:
Should I simply separate them with a `,`?

Comment: For some reason, this is not working. I applied the filter and the mails sent to me are also being redirected to the archive directly.